# PTIJ: When can I start learning again?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I was reviewing maseches Kesubos ([17a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.17a.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) when I came up upon the following line:

> ת"ר: מבטלין תלמוד תורה

Well, I have never heard that one from any of my Rabbis before, but of course, after reading that line, I dutifully followed Halacha and immediately closed my Gemara. But now I'm confused; when can I start learning again? I'm scared to look back into my Gemara after it just said I shouldn't. Can any of you help me? I haven't been able to learn for so long!

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Hahahahaha! Looks like you just learned something now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your own admission that it’s forbidden for you to learn, it would also be forbidden for us to teach you the answer to this question.

Comment: Scary ... We think similarly. See my comment, above...

Comment: @DanF Must be the name.

Comment: Well, if the answer to the question will be מתיר learning for me then it wouldn't be a problem, would it?

Answer (score 2):

See Rambam, Megillah 1:1, you may continue your Torah study after hearing the Megillah. Sayonara!

Answer (score 1):

It says that you're supposed to abandon the learning of Torah, meaning the first Five books. That's what they mean, there. (For God's sake! Did you look at the "Rushee" instead of Rash"I, or the "Toasty Feet?" instead of the Tosfot???)

You can still learn Nac"h, Gemarah, Mishnah, and all the other holy books.

Now, stop wasting time, and continue you're learning, **NOW!**.

Comment: Is "Rushee" Rashi for people in rush?

Comment: @Harel13 Indeed it is. Similar to the concept of "Shacharacing".